# A connection string that always connect

Tags: sql-server

I have a program that take 2 databases as input but (in my case) will only use one of those.

There is a `INI` file that looks like this:

```
DataSource1=irrelevant_yet_valid_string
Datasource2=DriverID=MSSQL;Server=blablabla;
OtherParameter=something very important
```

But in fact, I have to give a valid connection string for `DataSource1` as the program first check all the provided parameters are valid (even if useless)

I have to send the application and the INI file to a client.
I will ask him to modify Datasource2 to match his environment

Is there a connection string I can provide so that `DataSource1=magicString` would provide a valid connection on any (mostly vanilla) MSWindows system?

In this particular case, the host computer should run on  `Windows Server 2012 R2` system, but I will probably need the same on other windows host.

**Edit:** To clarify a bit:

My program do something like this

```
 My connection = new SqlConnection()
 My connection.ConnectionString = param_DataSource1;
 My connection.connect;
```

And that's the last time this connection will be used

This will crash if param_DataSource1 is random, but could there be a parameter that always work

A bit like

```
ping (someIP)
```

will always work if `someIP = "127.0.0.1"`

**Edit2:**
my problem is not specific to SQL server. In my exemple, the second conection is indeed SQL server, but it's mostly irrelevant (at most, I am sure that SQL server pilots can be used for this client)

What I want a connection string that work on a (somewhat standard) MSWindows system.

Comment: Of course, I could tell the client to put the same string for `dataSource1`and `dataSource2`. In fact, I did it before. but this seems to be confusing for some (the real name is more specific than dataSource1 so it is a bit awkard indeed)

Comment: You could use a client alias maybe? https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1620/how-to-setup-and-use-a-sql-server-alias/

Comment: @spaghettidba An alias is a slightly complex way to get a useful connection. What I want is a potentially useles connection that is valid without taking ANY action. A bit like 127.0.0.1 is a valid IP anywhere (`ping 127.0.0.1` will never fail)

Comment: So, you just want to find a way to populate DataSource1 with a connection string that always works when the client has a running Windows Server 2012 R2 box? that right?

Comment: powershell can return that value described here: https://serverfault.com/questions/682722/determine-hostname-of-windows-system-on-network

Comment: @Peter that works on a generic (whatever this means) windows. As I will certainly need this trick in other situations. If "generic" is not possible, then Windows Server 2012 R2 will be a good start

Comment: maybe try serverfault?

Comment: All you really need is a hostname isn't that right? A default instance of sql server on any windows server will identify as ```\\hostname```